# How to do pagination with PouchDB using Ionic Infinite Scroll?

Tags: ionic-framework, pagination, couchdb, infinite-scroll, pouchdb

Let's say I have **100 documents** (Note: total of documents will definitely increase). Getting all 100 documents at once will cause performance issue so I figured that I need to do infinite scroll and display, let's say, 15 documents on first load. Every time infinite scroll is triggered, it should get another 15 documents.

Basically, `docArr.length = 100`

First load: grab `docArr[0]` to `docArr[14]`

Trigger Infinite Scroll: grab `docArr[15]` to `docArr[29]` and so on until `docArr[99]` is grabbed too

In the [PouchDB FAQ on Pagination](https://pouchdb.com/2014/04/14/pagination-strategies-with-pouchdb.html), it's stated that `startkey`, `endkey`, `limit` and `skip` need to be used.

My document id is in the format `doc-1`. So I have `doc-1`, `doc-2`, `doc-3`, etc

I followed the suggested method to use so my code is;

```
var options = {limit : 15};
function fetchNextPage() {
  pouch.allDocs(options, function (err, response) {
    if (response && response.rows.length > 0) {
      let id_num = response[response.length - 1]._id.split('-').pop()
      //on first trigger, the line above should get '15'

      id_num = Number(id_num) + 1
      let id = 'doc-' + id_num 
      //on first trigger, id = 'doc-16'
      options.startkey = id;
      options.skip = 1;
    }
    // handle err or response
    
  });
}
```

However, when I do this way, when I trigger the infinite scroll, I only get the first 15 documents (from `element 0` to `element 14`) repeatedly even after I increased the id (which I use as the `startkey`).

How do I get the next 15 documents every time I trigger the infinite scroll (doing pagination) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on what is going on with the OP's code but the assumption that the `response.rows` of the first query to `_all_docs` is ordered so

| rows index | id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | doc-1 |
| 1 | doc-2 |
| 2 | doc-3 |
| 3 | doc-4 |
| 4 | doc-5 |
| 5 | doc-6 |
| 6 | doc-7 |
| 7 | doc-8 |
| 8 | doc-9 |
| 9 | doc-10 |
| 10 | doc-11 |
| 11 | doc-12 |
| 12 | doc-13 |
| 13 | doc-14 |
| 14 | doc-15 |

is **wrong**.  Document id's are strings and as such follow the collation rules documented at  CouchDB documentation [3.2.2.5. Collation Specification](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html?highlight=collation#collation-specification).

This should be the *actual* sequence of document id's returned by the initial call to `_all_docs` according to the format of the document ids specified by the OP:

| rows index | id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | doc-1 |
| 1 | doc-10 |
| 2 | doc-100 |
| 3 | doc-11 |
| 4 | doc-12 |
| 5 | doc-13 |
| 6 | doc-14 |
| 7 | doc-15 |
| 8 | doc-16 |
| 9 | doc-17 |
| 10 | doc-18 |
| 11 | doc-19 |
| 12 | doc-2 |
| 13 | doc-20 |
| 14 | doc-21 |

Hence the calculation of the next set of results is flawed

```js
id_num = Number(id_num) + 1
let id = 'doc-' + id_num   
options.startkey = id;
```

Calculating the next id is a bad idea and wholly unnecessary.  Rather use the id of the *last document*, e.g.

```js
    let result = await db.allDocs(options);        
    if(result.rows.length) {
      // do something with results
      // get next page of docs?
      if(result.rows.length === options.limit) {        
        options.startkey = result.rows.pop().id;
        options.skip = 1;
        // repeat 
      }
    }
```

This snippet uses `setTimeout` to grab 15 documents per second, logs the document ids to the console, and exits when the number of documents returned is less than the `limit`, which signals the end of the results.

```js
// canned test documents
function getDocsToInstall() {
  let docs = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    docs.push({
      _id: `doc-${i}`
    });
  }
  return docs;
}

let db;

// init db instance
async function initDb() {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
}

function update(result) {
  console.log(result.rows.map(d => d.id).join(','));
}

initDb().then(async() => {
  let options = {
    limit: 15,
    include_docs: false,
    reduce: false
  };
  async function timerFn() {
    let result = await db.allDocs(options);
    if (result.rows.length) {
      update(result);
      // get next page of docs
      if (result.rows.length === options.limit) {
        options.startkey = result.rows.pop().id;
        options.skip = 1;
        // repeat
        setTimeout(timerFn, 1000);
      } else {
        console.log("All docs processed ");
      }
    }
  };
  timerFn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
```